# is confounded by

Tags: meaning, usage

- Something ***is confounded by*** something

What does it mean?

- The dream of welfare *is confounded by* the fear of democracy

Comment: [**confound**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confound) (sense 2a): **REFUTE** - example usage: *sought to confound his arguments*.

Answer (score 0):

The Online Etymology Dictionary has two pages on this, [here](https://www.etymonline.com/word/confound) and [here](https://www.etymonline.com/word/confounded).